# Sum rule and $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am trying to obtain a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1}$ by a combinatorial argument. Unfortunately, nothing seems to strike. If I write this as $n\sum 2^{k-1}-\sum k2^{k-1}$ then I do have the first term $n\sum 2^{k-1}=n2^{n+1}-n2^n-n$ but am unable to make sense of the second term.

Can someone help please?

Comment: You may as well sum only up to $n-1$, since $n-n=0$. Or maybe rewrite the sum in terms of $n-1=t$ or something.

Comment: I don't know about a combinatorial argument, but if you let $f(x)=\sum(1+x)^k$, differentiate, and let $x=1$, you should be able to evaluate your sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The question specifically asks for using the sum rule.

Comment: Then maybe you had better tell us what "the sum rule" is!

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) for ideas.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Usually, the sum rule refers to the fact that if you partition a set of objects, the number of objects in the original set is the sum of the sizes of the subsets in the partition.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The sum rule is: If $S=\cup_{i=1}^t S_i$ is a union of disjoint sets $S_i$, then $|S|=\sum_{i=1}^t |S_i|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

How many binary sequences of length $n$ contain at least two 0's, with the second 0 occurring in position $n-k+1$?

Comment: This is how I proceeded: The 1st zero may be selected at any of the 1st $n-k$ positions, and there remain $k-1$ positions to fill arbitrarily(the ones before the first zero and the $n-k+1$th positions are fixed). This yields the desired sum. Alternatively, we just have $\tbinom{n}{2}2^{n-2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite: $\binom{n}{2}2^{n-2}$ over-counts pretty badly, since the positions of the two 0's are not uniquely determined.  Instead, see if you can count the number of sequences with exactly one 0 and exactly no 0's, and subtract from the total number of binary sequences.

Comment: That would be $2^n-n-1$?

Comment: @Shahab That's right!

Comment: @NickPeterson what was the motivation for using a binary sequence of length $n$?  Why consider the position $n-k+1$?

Answer (score 2):

Start with
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}\tag{1}
$$
then take the derivative and multitply by $x$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k=\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}\tag{2}
$$
Subtract $(2)$ from $n$ times $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)x^k
&=\frac{nx^{n+2}-nx^{n+1}-nx^2+nx}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1}-nx^2+(n-1)x}{(x-1)^2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Pluggng $x=2$ into $(3)$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)2^k=2^{n+1}-2n-2\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. For each $k\in S$, $(n-k)2^{k-1}$ is the number of ways to pick any subset of $\{1,\dots,k-1\}$ and any one element of $\{k+1,k+2,\dots,n\}$. This is exactly the number of ways to pick a subset $A$ of $S$ such that $|A|\ge 2$, and the second-largest element of $A$ is $k$. Let $\mathscr{A}_k$ be the family of such subsets of $S$. If you pick a subset of $S$ of cardinality at least $2$, it belongs to a unique $\mathscr{A}_k$. Thus, the sum is the number of subsets of $S$ of cardinality at least $2$, which is ... ?

Comment: $2^n-n-1$. Thanks.

Comment: @Shahab: That's right. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on robjohn's answer:

If
$f(x) 
= \sum_{k=1}^n k x^k
$,
and
$g(x) 
= \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k) x^k
$,
then

$\begin{align}
f(x)x^{-n}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k-n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k) x^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k) x^{-k}\\
&=n+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (n-k) x^{-k}\\
&=n+g(1/x)\\
\end{align}
$

so
$f(1/x)x^n = n+g(x)$
or
$g(x) = x^n f(1/x) - n$.